# Homogenizing columns that mix NaNs and empty strings

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a relatively large csv (~200Mb) dataset into pandas with some columns containing either a weird "  ." string (which is actually an empty cell), or NaN. Other columns contain either NaN or empty strings. In the first case, I want to transform the weird string to NaN. In the second case, I want to convert NaNs to empty strings. I have been trying a few methods but they are not doing what I want. Note that I do not want to use dropna, or anything that affects other rows.

For example

`df['Col1'].replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)`

included 0s in the some rows of the column.

As an example, I want to convert:

```
 Col1   Col2  Col
 ' .'   NaN    3 
 NaN   '  .'   1
```

to

```
  Col1 Col2 Col
  NaN  NaN  3
  NaN  NaN  1
```

and convert

```
 Col1 Col2 Col
 ""   NaN  3 
 NaN  5    1
 5    3    4
```

to

```
 Col1 Col2 Col
 ""   ""   3 
 ""   5    1
 5    3    4
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The first case is easy. But the second case... why would you want to do that?

Comment: For several reasons. One of them, for example, I want to get dummies from these columns. Pandas will create  column "" and a column nan.

Comment: No, pandas ignores NaNs. OTOH, those empty strings won't. Do you want them ignored or no?

Comment: I want to make them consistent across the column. These problems are legacies from how the original excel file was generated, and it does create problems when I want to work with these columns.

Comment: For example, I am getting problems adding elements of Col1 and Col2 when I have this sort of heterogeneity

Comment: I see. In that case, wouldn't it be better converting everything to ONLY NaNs, or ONLY empty string columns? Why two different things for different data?

Comment: That could be a solution too, I guess. It seems that having both cases in the same column is a problem. In any case, I am having a hard time in both directions.

Comment: Well, I've added an answer enumerating on what we've just discussed.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following code:-

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace('.','').replace(' ','').fillna('')
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].replace('.','').replace(' ','').fillna('')
```

i am replacing first `'.'`  and empty spaces with the `default value`, then filling all `nan` values also to the `default value`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will try

Comment: @JuliannoSambatti This may or may not work. If you have other strings with these characters, you don't want to go blindly replacing whatever.

Comment: @JuliannoSambatti This also does not scale. I'd imagine bad performance on data with a lot of columns. You'd have to loop over every single column, making 2 replace calls and one fillna call each time. Wow.

Comment: It is so weird. It inserted some "0" in a few places.

Comment: I agree this process maybe slow but taking `str` type in consideration, we may serve our purpose.  @JuliannoSambatti this will not add `0`, but numpy, so you can first clean data in type `str` then convert to `float` or `int` as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be better to decide on a *single value* (either NaNs, or empty strings), and convert your column values to that.

When reading your data, specify a `quotechar` and `na_values` parameter.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls', quotechar="'", na_values=[''])
```

This should eliminate empty strings, converting them to NaN (handling the second case). Next, for cases such as your first, use `replace` with a regular expression -

```
df.replace('^\s*\.?\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

   Col1  Col2  Col
0   NaN   NaN    3
1   NaN   NaN    1
```

The expression matches cells with whitespaces and the optional `'.'`.

Comment: Thanks, I think the data complexity produces some unexpected behaviour.  It does replace '  .'. But, when I apply you code, some entire rows (I have about 100 columns), apparently random rows, are set to 0.

Comment: @JuliannoSambatti `replace` can do many things, but that is not one of them. I'd need to see what the data that is causing this looks like, or else I cannot answer your question.

Comment: It seems the problem lies in reading the data. I am using jupyter notebook for testing. Have you had any problem using this?

Comment: @JuliannoSambatti No, never. That is a weird issue to have.

Comment: Never mind. Before I bother you more, let me do some tests and try to narrow down the problem. Thank you for your help. I partially solved the problem.